# Netbeans does not give me wadl file

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy a RESTful application with Netbeans to a remote server (with domain name "agdata.se") by following [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html). Once I've built and deployed, then entering the url "http://agdata.se:8080/WebTest/test-resbeans.html" I get the following error message:

"Cannot access WADL: Please restart your RESTful application, and refresh this page."

When I look in the project folder and unzip the war file, there's no wadl to be found. It's like Netbeans never created one.

I created the project (let's call it project A) using dedicated folders. I choosed Java EE 6Web and JavaServer Faces as the framework. I didn't configure the framework so I didn't choose PrimeFaces or any other of the components.

I then made a "RESTFful web service from a database" by rightclicking the project node. I created the datasource, just like the guide said, since I use a MySQL-database and not a Derby.

I left "Generate Named Query Annotations for Persistent Fields" checked.
I didn't check "Use Jersey Specific Features".

Then, I created another Web Application, also with Faces as framework. Letäs call this project B.

I run "Test RESTful Web Services" and check "Web Test Client in Project". I then choose project B and I can deploy and build it without any errors. I then enter the REST-test url into Firefox and it says it cannot access the WADL file. Again, there is no such file in the project folder when I look into the war file. Just to be clear, this is a remote server I'm deploying to, not localhost. The server is Ubuntu 13, I'm on a Mac OSX.

Thankful for all the help I can get!

Comment: The WADL file is generated dynamically by the J2EE container i.e. Jersey